# How to view an MSSQL layer/table with mixed geometry types using QGIS (2.18)?

Tags: qgis

I have a connection to data in an MSSQL database. The key (spatial) table records points, polygons, and lines all within the **one** table. Is there a more graceful way to handle this data on QGIS - which is more advanced than setting up three separate filtered views on the database, one for lines, one for polygons and one for points?

....

The following are details which may or may not be relevant:
- QGIS 2.18
- MSSQL / SQL Server 2014 (12)
- there are no multi-polygons/multi-lines/multi-points
- The database administrator has successfully set me up with filtered views (I don't have direct database access, but close communication)
- I'd actually like to be able to filter the raw data myself using tools at the QGIS end of this connection.
- QGIS seems to decide on one of the three geometry types (I'm guessing based on something like the first entry in the table) and I can't find any way to change this, so from the raw data I can render only lines.
- I tried some basic edits with a text file to the QGIS project to see if I could force QGIS to recognise the layer as being points/polygons but failed.

I note that there are a selection of somewhat similar questions already asked, but these are I think either very old (referring to old versions of QGIS) or unanswered.